# Instant Payment Notification order description blank in Express Checkout (NVP)

Tags: email, paypal, notifications

I've successfully (almost!) integrated Paypal's express checkout on a site.  The order preview shows the order description, price and quantity.  Payment is made within the sandbox and the buyer account is debited and the vendor account is credited with the right amount.

The system generates the test Instant Payment Notification (IPN) emails and all looks fine except the order description within the e-mail is blank.

My instinct is that it's something obvious like a value not being set correctly for the label but I can't find what it is in the docs.

Here is how I'm setting the data for the order items:

```
$nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=". $this->itemName;
$nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=". $this->itemNumber;
$nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=". $this->itemDesc;
$nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=". $this->_addVAT( $this->itemAmount );
$nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=". $this->itemQty;
```

I did try using what looks to be a deprecated format of "L_NAME0", which didn't work.

Again, this works for the previewing screen and the payments, it's just the IPN e-mails which don't populate with the order items.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

You need to pass the information after going back to the vendor's site.  The e-mail is generated from the information sent in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call.