# Instant Payment Notification order description blank in Express Checkout

Tags: php, email, paypal, express, notifications

i am trying to integrate Paypal Express. The order almost works,the price und the name of the items are shown on in the cart of paypal, so i think the SetExpresscheckout works. My problem is that the DoExpressCheckoutPayment works wrong, because in the mail the order description is blank although i give the information:

```
$padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token).
                        '&PAYERID='.urlencode($playerid).
                        '&PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE").
                        '&AMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
                      '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).          
                        '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0='.urlencode("Name").  
                        '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0='.urlencode("Description").  
                        '&CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode);

    $paypal= new MyPayPal();
    $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);
```

Here is the same problem: [Instant Payment Notification order description blank in Express Checkout (NVP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651304/instant-payment-notification-order-description-blank-in-express-checkout-nvp/18432818#18432818)

but the solution does not help. i hope you can help me. sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal doesn't recognize your line item details (`L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0` or `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0`) because you didn't include the line item quantity or price, and you didn't include the item subtotal.

Ideally, you should be passing full details on the items that you sold, but if you just want to pass a summary, you need to add the following parameters to your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call:

- `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0` (set this to the order total)
- `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0` (set this to `1`)
- `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT` (set this to the order total)